# AWS Cloudwatch GetMetricData Discrepancy between CLI and SDKs

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to perform a simple CloudWatch query to get some metric data. I want to get the actual metrics. Using the AWS CLI I am getting the expected behavior.  However, using client SDKs (tried both Python's Boto and Java's SDKs), the same (seeming) query is not returning my metrics.

My query criteria is defined in `query.json`:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "test",
        "MetricStat": {
            "Metric": {
                "Namespace": "MyNamespace",
                "MetricName": "MyMetric",
                "Dimensions": [
                    {
                        "Name": "SOURCE",
                        "Value": "TEST"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Period": 3600,
            "Stat": "SampleCount",
            "Unit":"Seconds"
            },
        "ReturnData": true
    }
]
```

**CLI** this works. Returns my metric value and timestamp

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --max-items 10 --start-time "2020-05-01T00:00:00Z" --end-time "2020-06-01T00:00:00Z" --metric-data-queries file://./query.json
{
    "MetricDataResults": [
        {
            "Id": "test",
            "Label": "MyMetric",
            "Timestamps": [
                "2020-05-15T13:00:00Z",
...
            ],
            "Values": [
                1.0,
...
            ],
            "StatusCode": "Complete"
        }
    ],
    "Messages": []
}
```

**Boto** won't return the metrics, even from the same file

```
In [77]: cw.get_metric_data(MetricDataQueries=json.load(open("query.json")), StartTime=datetime.datetime(2020,5,1), EndTime=datetime.datetime(2020,6,1), MaxDatapoints=10)
Out [77]: {'MetricDataResults': [{'Id': 'test',
   'Label': 'MyMetric',
   'Timestamps': [],       <--Why isn't this populated?
   'Values': [],
   'StatusCode': 'PartialData'}],
```

**Java** Approximately the same input criteria

```
MetricDataQuery query = new MetricDataQuery().withReturnData(true);
query.setMetricStat(new MetricStat()
                    .withStat("SampleCount")
                    .withPeriod(36000)
                    .withMetric(
                            new Metric()
                                    .withMetricName("MyMetric")
                                    .withNamespace("MyNamespace)
                                    .withDimensions(new Dimension()
                                            .withName("SOURCE")
                                            .withValue("TEST"))));

cw.getMetricData(new GetMetricDataRequest()
                    .withStartTime(Date.from(Instant.now().minus(100, ChronoUnit.DAYS)))
                    .withEndTime(Date.from(Instant.now()))
                    .withScanBy(ScanBy.TimestampDescending)
                    .withMaxDatapoints(10)
                    .withMetricDataQueries(query))


// Result ==> {Id: TestQuery,Label: MyMetric,Timestamps: [],Values: [],StatusCode: PartialData,Messages: []}
```

I haven't a clue why the cli will return metric values, but both CDKs I've tried don't seem to. Any hints?

Comment: Maybe due to differences how cli and sdk treat dates? One can use utc time, the other your local time? Have you tried extending the range in boto3? The time range is one day, maybe your data point falls out of range if your local time is use, or utc time?

Comment: Good thought, and I think you're right, my boto example misused date specs. Still no change though, I have full metrics over the time range.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was with `MaxDataPoints`.

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricData.html) :

> The maximum number of data points the request should return before paginating. If you omit this, the default of 100,800 is used.

However, in practice, setting that value too low causes **no** values to be returned. I can speculate that that value is being used to limit the number of metric points or periods examined in the query, not returned.

```
In [77]: cw.get_metric_data(MetricDataQueries=json.load(open("query.json")), StartTime=datetime.datetime(2020,1,5), EndTime=datetime.datetime(2020,1,6), MaxDatapoints=10)
...
{'MetricDataResults': [{'Id': 'test',
   'Label': 'Errors',
   'Timestamps': [],
   'Values': [],
   'StatusCode': 'PartialData'}],...
```

vs

```
In [78]: cw.get_metric_data(MetricDataQueries=json.load(open("query.json")), StartTime=datetime.datetime(2020,1,5), EndTime=datetime.datetime(2020,1,6), MaxDatapoints=1000)
...
{'MetricDataResults': [{'Id': 'test',
   'Label': 'Errors',
   'Timestamps': [datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 27, 15, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 27, 14, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 27, 13, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
...
```

Maybe someone can explain this behavior?